# Create dynamic HTML form using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I've been googling and googling but completely stuck on this.

I have a GET request that retrieves some JSON containing a list of users. However the list of users changes.

I want to generate a simple HTML form that contains the names of the users, and then an input field so that they can be given a rating. I then need to gather the ratings and send a POST request in JSON.

What would be the best way to approach this? I was thinking of looping through the users and just displaying them with a text input type but then I have no idea how I can use the form data to send the POST request!

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You have no idea how to gather the data, or how to send it ?

Comment: The POST is simply the `action` attribute of the form. State where you want it to post to, and it will handle it automatically. As for retrieving the information, do you have access to back-end languages such as PHP? They would make your task much easier :) Otherwise you'd be looking at using AJAX to retrieve the information and inject it after the form was built, rather than building the form with the content dynamically injected ;)

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention, no access to any backend languages

Comment: what format is the user list json in? just an array of strings?

Comment: just a simple string array yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Populate UI base on JSON**

HTML:

```
 <form id="user_list">
  <div>

   </div>
  <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
```

JS:

```
var obj = {
  users:[{name:"user 1"},{name:"user 2"}]
}

var user_list = $("#user_list>div");

obj.users.forEach(function(user,index){

    user_list.append("<div>"+
                     "<h1>" + user.name + "</h1>"+
                     "<input type='text' id='user_"+ index +"'/>"+
                     "</div>");
});
```

**Send selected values to server.**

- **Option 1**

If you make this page full post back when click on submit, you have to change text boxes as following

```
"<input type='text' name='[user_"+ index +"]'/>"+
```

In server request object, you will be give as array of key/values.

- **Option 2**

If you are planing to make AJAX request, again you can loop though the text boxes and build the JSON format which you want in back-end and pass though the AJAX.

```
  $("input[type='text']").each(function(input){
       $(input).val();
    });
```

Comment: Many thanks for your post, this is exactly what I was looking for!